# Editing page in wordpress - page not in content manager

Tags: wordpress

I need to edit a page on my wordpress site, but the page doesn't show on the "Pages" feature. This page is accessible over a top menu that I can edit over the themes/template editing. However I cannot find a way to edit it or even find it on my file manager.

[image: Menu edit mode screenshot]

This is the page URL: http://protector-canum.de/linkliste/

I just need to add some content to it.

Anyone aware of how I can get this done?

---

Thanks!

Comment: When you are logged into Wordpress do you see the WP Admin bar at the top of the page? If so do you have an option to Edit Page from there?

Comment: just open any page and replace the post_id in the url with 1458.
what happens then?

Comment: Hi Paul, it opens up the Menu to edit instead. However I used Xandl's method and it worked. @Xandl where did you get that number from?  :)

Comment: @Overdrive like stated below - most of the time, IDs are added to the body tag. Since you can edit it, I guess it must be in the list somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Check the css class of your body tag and look for post-id-XXXX

use that number in your admin url